# DJIBaseProduct model is UnknownAircraft DJI SDK

Tags: ios, dronekit, dji-sdk

getFirmwarePackageVersionWithCompletion error 1012

`-(void) sdkManagerProductDidChangeFrom:(DJIBaseProduct*) oldProduct to:(DJIBaseProduct*) newProduct{
    ShowResult(newProduct.model);
}`

The newProduct variable is not null yet it says unknown aircraft for the model property. Anythoughts?

I am also getting an error (1012) when I call `getFirmwarePackageVersionWithCompletion`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just connect your iOS device to the Remote Controller and not turn on the aircraft? Or the Remote Controller doesn't connect with the aircraft successfully?(Please check if the Remote Controller's light is green, it means connect successfully). Then the `getFirmwarePackageVersionWithCompletion` method should be invoked when the newProduct is not nil.